# Behavior of UIView bringSubviewToFront When Parameter Isn't a Subview of Receiver

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I was wondering if the behavior is defined for `[UIView bringSubviewToFront:]` when the parameter and receiver are both valid views, but the parameter isn't a subview of the receiver. No explanation in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/bringSubviewToFront:). Can anyone find a reference, or barring that, has anyone experimented with this?